Not Receiving Data from a Server Sending SSE to Client in Flutter
I am trying to receive data from a server that sends updates every 5 seconds using Server-Sent Events (SSE) to a browser. My goal is to capture that data in my Flutter app and yield it in a function.
What I've Done So Far:
I am using the flutter_client_sse package for subscribing to SSE streams. Below is the code I am working with:
Stream<dynamic> fetchRoutingStream() async* {
    // Fetch the token asynchronously
    SharedPrefsRepository sharedPrefsRepository =
        SharedPrefsRepository(provider: SharedPrefsProvider());
    String token = await sharedPrefsRepository.getAccessToken();

    final url = 'https://example.com/api/v1/web/route/';

    // Subscribe to SSE
    SSEClient.subscribeToSSE(
        method: SSERequestType.GET,
        url: url,
        header: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}
    ).listen(
        (event) {
            // Log the event details
            print('Id: ' + (event.id ?? ''));
            print('Event: ' + (event.event ?? ''));
            print('Data: ' + (event.data ?? ''));
        },
    );
}


The Problem:
The problem is that the code never seems to reach the .listen() part. The print statements within the listener never get executed.
I've confirmed that the API sends data every 5 seconds (verified with browser developer tools). It seems that the connection is not established correctly, or I am missing something with the SSE setup in Flutter.
My Questions:
Why is the listener not working and failing to print any data received from the SSE?
What could be the issue with the SSE subscription or how should I debug this?


Extra Notes:
I’ve attached a screenshot showing that the data is indeed being sent to the API every 5 seconds.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I encountered the same issue recently, and I'd like to share my experience and solution with you.
This is a common issue when working with  and occurs regardless of the browser you're using (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc.).
Interestingly, if you test the same functionality on a mobile device, it typically works without any issues.
To ensure the solution works seamlessly on both web and mobile platforms, you can use the following workaround:
// sse_client.dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Stream<String>> getSSEStream(Uri url, Map<String, String> headers) async {
  final request = http.Request('GET', url);
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  return (await http.Client().send(request)).stream.transform(utf8.decoder);
}

// sse_client_web.dart
import 'package:fetch_client/fetch_client.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Stream<String>> getSSEStream(Uri url, Map<String, String> headers) async {
  final fetchClient = FetchClient(mode: RequestMode.cors);
  final request = http.Request('GET', url);
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  final response = await fetchClient.send(request);
  return response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder);
}


// 1. IMPORTANT!! The key part of all is this
import 'sse_client.dart' if (dart.library.js) 'sse_client_web.dart'; // Will be used on main.dart

// 2. Notice something important, im using mercure for this example in
static const String _hubUrl = 'https://mercure.your-application-baseurl/.well-known/mercure';

// main.dart Full test file
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dart_jsonwebtoken/dart_jsonwebtoken.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_client_sse/flutter_client_sse.dart';
import 'sse_client.dart' if (dart.library.js) 'sse_client_web.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Mercure SSE Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MercureSSEDemo(),
    );
  }
}

// Modelo para las notificaciones
class NotificationMessage {
  final String message;
  final DateTime timestamp;

  NotificationMessage({
    required this.message,
    required this.timestamp,
  });

  factory NotificationMessage.fromSSE(SSEModel sseModel) {
    print('Datos recibidos SSE: ${sseModel.data}');
    
    try {
      // Eliminar el último carácter de nueva línea si existe
      final data = (sseModel.data ?? '').trimRight();
      
      // Intentar decodificar el JSON si viene en ese formato
      Map<String, dynamic>? jsonData;
      try {
        jsonData = json.decode(data);
        print('JSON decodificado: $jsonData');
      } catch (e) {
        print('No es JSON válido, usando datos en bruto');
      }

      return NotificationMessage(
        message: jsonData?['message'] ?? data,
        timestamp: DateTime.now(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error procesando mensaje: $e');
      return NotificationMessage(
        message: 'Error al procesar mensaje: ${sseModel.data}',
        timestamp: DateTime.now(),
      );
    }
  }
}

// Service para manejar la lógica de Mercure
class MercureService {
  static const String _hubUrl = 'https://mercure.your-application-baseurl/.well-known/mercure';
  static const String _jwtSecret = '!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!';
  
  static final List<String> _topics = [
    'https://your-application-baseurl/notifications/all',
  ];

  static String generateJWT() {
    final jwt = JWT(
      {
        'mercure': {
          'subscribe': ['*'],
          'publish': []
        }
      },
      header: {'alg': 'HS256'},
    );

    return jwt.sign(
      SecretKey(_jwtSecret),
      algorithm: JWTAlgorithm.HS256,
    );
  }

  static Uri getSubscriptionUrl() {
    return Uri.parse(_hubUrl).replace(
      queryParameters: {'topic': _topics},
    );
  }

  static Future<Stream<String>> subscribe() async {
    final url = getSubscriptionUrl();
    final headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${generateJWT()}',
      'Accept': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    };

    return getSSEStream(url, headers);
  }
}

class MercureSSEDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const MercureSSEDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<MercureSSEDemo> createState() => _MercureSSEDemoState();
}

class _MercureSSEDemoState extends State<MercureSSEDemo> {
  late StreamSubscription<String> _sseSubscription;
  final List<NotificationMessage> _notifications = [];
  bool _isConnected = false;
  final _reconnectInterval = const Duration(seconds: 5);
  int _reconnectAttempts = 0;
  static const int _maxReconnectAttempts = 5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSSE();
  }

  void _initSSE() async {
    try {
      final stream = await MercureService.subscribe();
      _sseSubscription = stream.listen(
        (data) {
          print('Datos recibidos: $data');
          // Procesar los datos...
          final notification = NotificationMessage(
            message: data,
            timestamp: DateTime.now(),
          );
          setState(() {
            _notifications.insert(0, notification);
            _isConnected = true;
          });
        },
        onError: _handleError,
        onDone: _handleConnectionClosed,
      );
      setState(() => _isConnected = true);
      _reconnectAttempts = 0;
    } catch (e) {
      _handleError(e);
    }
  }

  void _handleError(dynamic error) {
    print('002');

    if (!mounted) return;

    print('Error en SSE: $error');
    setState(() => _isConnected = false);
    _attemptReconnect();
  }

  void _handleConnectionClosed() {
    print('003');

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() => _isConnected = false);
    _attemptReconnect();
  }

  void _attemptReconnect() {
    if (_reconnectAttempts >= _maxReconnectAttempts) {
      print('Máximo número de intentos de reconexión alcanzado');
      return;
    }

    Future.delayed(_reconnectInterval, () {
      if (mounted && !_isConnected) {
        _reconnectAttempts++;
        print('Intento de reconexión $_reconnectAttempts de $_maxReconnectAttempts');
        _initSSE();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sseSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mercure SSE Demo'),
        actions: [
          ConnectionStatusIndicator(isConnected: _isConnected),
        ],
      ),
      body: NotificationsList(notifications: _notifications),
    );
  }
}

class ConnectionStatusIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isConnected;

  const ConnectionStatusIndicator({
    super.key,
    required this.isConnected,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      width: 16,
      height: 16,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: isConnected ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NotificationsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<NotificationMessage> notifications;

  const NotificationsList({
    super.key,
    required this.notifications,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: notifications.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final notification = notifications[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(notification.message),
          subtitle: Text(
            notification.timestamp.toLocal().toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

I hope this helps! Let me know if you need further clarification or run into any other issues!
